# Is there any way to open .doc file in Android?

Tags: android

I have created a app that displays all the content from res/raw folder.

I need that when i click on .doc file it should open and I can view its content.

please help me.

I have ThinkFree.

```
enter code here
public class FileList extends ListActivity {

public static final Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Field>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.weekofday, fields));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not possible. A third-party application will not be able to read a Word document out of your raw resources.

At best, you could copy the file from the raw resource someplace (e.g., external storage), then call `startActivity()` on an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` that has a `Uri` pointing to the readable copy and also has the proper MIME type.

Of course, this will only work on a device that has a Word document viewer on it.

Comment: on nexus one/htc hero file will be opened in quickoffice.

Comment: @bhups: The Nexus One does not ship with QuickOffice, or at least it did not back when I bought it.

Comment: I got nexus one 4 months ago, and it has quickoffice.

Comment: @bhups: OK, mine was from January -- they must have added it as a pre-load somewhere along the line. Suffice it to say, not every Nexus One will have QuickOffice.

Comment: @CommonsWare same thing will work of remote file URL with streaming? httk://sample.com/example.doc  ?  ( This is old question Sorry)

Comment: @LOG_TAG: There many be office apps that can read from HTTP, but I would not assume that all can.