# How to open a .doc file stored in SD card in browser?

Tags: android

I have a .doc file stored in the SD card. I have to open it using the browser.
I used

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
File file = new File("/sdcard/ValidateLibrary.doc"); 
intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile(file),"text/html");
```

in the manifest file i wrote:

```
<activity android:name=".TextFileShow">
    <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="myaction"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But it opens the "message compose".

I have to open the ValidateLibrary.doc file inside a browser.
How do i do that?

Comment: What action is your Intent using? Also "doc/*" is not the MIME type for a Word Document. It is "application/msword".

Comment: Well, I don't have any clear idea about the manifest file. So, please do tell me the changes required there.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setType("application/*"); i have done like this to open files in SD card

Comment: @abhi, that opens a dialogue- asking to choose from a list of apps- browser, email, etc. I don't want that dialogue.
I want to open the ".doc" type of file. What type did you open?

Comment: hai @pallavi intent.setDataAndType("filepath,"type"); to open files. but for .doc files you have to sreach it seems

Comment: @Nick, do we have to have msWord installed on the phone/emulator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075822/is-there-any-way-to-open-doc-file-in-android see this post pallavi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080673/answer/submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to open it using the browser.

I am not aware of any Web browser on the face of the planet, other than perhaps Internet Explorer, that is capable of natively displaying Microsoft Word documents. I am not aware of any Web browser for Android that is capable of natively displaying Microsoft Word documents.

With regards to your Java source code snippet:

- `text/html` is not the MIME type for Microsoft Word.
- Never hardcode paths like `/sdcard`, particularly since it is wrong for many devices. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get at the root of external storage.
- Just creating an `Intent` will do you little good. If you want to display a Word document using some document viewer that the user might have installed, you would need to use `ACTION_VIEW` in the `Intent` constructor, then set the path/type as you are doing, then call `startActivity()`.

> in the manifest file i wrote:

I have no idea why this is here. It certainly has nothing obvious to do with your Java code snippet, and it has nothing obvious to do with this question.

> I have to open the ValidateLibrary.doc file inside a browser. How do i do that?

Step #1: Write a Web browser.

Step #2: Augment your Web browser to be able to display Microsoft Word documents. This may involve you having to license some patents and will probably take a few developer-decades to write.

Step #3: Convince users to install your Web/Word browser.

It would be simpler for you to simply start up an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on the Word document, then direct users to the Market to install some third-party application that handles Word documents if the user does not have one installed.

Comment: can you advice me some word doc viewers? I know "Quick Office", but it is not a freeware.

Comment: @Pallavi: I am not aware of any freeware Word document viewers, though you are welcome to search the Market to see if anything shows up that meets your needs.