# Android: can't share files

Tags: android, share

I have a problems, when I'm trying to share files via Bluetooth, Dropbox, etc.
Here's my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);   
        File file = new File(opt.getPath());
        String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
        String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        intent.setType(mimetype);
        String path = "file://" + file.getAbsolutePath();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);   
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File"));
```

For example, when I select an image, getFileExtensionFromUrl returns empty string.
And when mimetype is correct(application/pdf for example), I also can't share file(I've getting message "Unsupported file type"). What's wrong am I doing?

**Update**
I partially solved this problem by myself.
Here's the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);   
        File file = new File(opt.getPath());
        String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getAbsolutePath());
        String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        intent.setType(mimetype);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));   
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File"));
```

But getFileExtensionFromUrl function for example still returns empty string for video(tests on *.wmv)

**Update.** Solved that promlem by using this code:

```
int dotPos = file.getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1;
```

String ext = file.getName().substring(dotPos);

and removing

```
String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getAbsolutePath());
```